# abas-ERP: Excecute a FO-Service-Program from a cronjob

Tags: linux, shell, erp, abas

I need to run a service program, written in FO for abas-ERP continuous.

I heard about some already existing scripts for calling service programs from the shell. If that is possible I could simply use a cronjob for starting this script.

But I don't know exactly where to find a template for these shell scripts, which conditions have to be complied and if there are any restrictions.
For Example: Is it possible to call several FO-programs successively (this might be important relating to blocking licences)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use batchlg.sh

```
batchlg.sh 'FOP-Name' [ -PASSARGS ] [Parameter ...]
```

Comment: I'm not completely sure how to configure this. I copied the batchlg.sh from the s3/bin/-Folder into my client-folder and tried to execute it as the client user. The description says the calling user have to have a valid EKS-password with turned of password request. But how can I reach that from the shell? How do I have to configure a linux user? Or can i append the password information by using the PASSARGS?

Comment: Okay I solved this by using the client user and setting the HOMEDIR, MANDANTDIR, EKSPASSWORT and SPR Environment Variables exclusive before executing the batchlg.sh-script

Comment: You can read the documentation (online help) how to configure batchlg. In short you have to create a linux user batchlg and an abas user with systemlogin name = batchlg and no password. To prevent users to login by just hitting return you can remove all register commands (standard, user and group). And you don't have to copy batchlg.sh anywhere!

Answer (score 2):

You can use edpinfosys.sh and execute infosystem TEXTZEIGEN per cronjob.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, Frank. Maybe you can explain a little more detailed where to find and how to use..

Comment: does anyone know what TEXTZEIGEN is called in english? I think we should keep it as internationally usable as possible, though abas makes it hard for us

Comment: I found this script in the s3-Folder. But I'm not sure if it's possible to run a FOP placed in a ow-Folder directly for a specific client? May this script be just for infosystems like the name already says? (=

Comment: @Breeze: Unfortunately "TEXTZEIGEN" is the swd for the infosystem. It's a identifier and I'm not sure if this infosystem get a different swd in a English installation.  The idno is a more unique identifier (for alive objects) and the default infosystems have the same idno's in every installation. The idno for  "TEXTZEIGEN" is 10169. Maybe this is more helpful?

Comment: I'll send you an example later this afternoon!

Comment: Okay, thank you! Can you tell me something about blocking licences with this method? I use a batch user and it doesn't seem to block a licence while executing my FO-program.

Comment: Every batchlg call needs his own license. This is why all our cronjobs start  between 12:00 and 12:30 or after 18:00. edpinfosys.sh, edpimport.sh and edpexport.sh also need their own license when they are called from the crontab. If you call edp*.sh from your FO-programm you typically use G|einmalpassw (which runs the programm under the license of the current user)